# Background image size cover not working in mobile browsers

Tags: css

I encountered an issue on displaying a site when in mobile. The images background size that is set to `cover` works well on desktop but when in chrome android phone it won't get full screen. I know this was asked before and tried them but no luck for me.

What I tried is:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also tried adding media query to display smaller background image to fit mobile screen but no luck.

Media Query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
body, html {
        background-image: url('../images/mobile-bg.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: why `overflow: hidden;` ? what happens if you change it to visible?
could you give a jsfidle for easier debuging?

Comment: Just added it up hoping for a miracle.

Comment: I think you should define `<meta>` tag with settings for mobile viewports: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: usually attribute `background-image` is assigned to `body` not `html`

Comment: @Banzay, I already set the `<meta>` tag but not working.